# Why transform: scale() seems to be translateX?

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I use framer-motion with next params:

```
  whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
  whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
```

But instead of scaling it seems to be translating by X.

This item has next css properties:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin-left: 50px;
```

look a video:

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/13121928?key=24fb66bc4fd804516e16d34aaf573a84

Comment: I guess that origin of the text is on the left so scaling it moves it to the right. See [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)